# CONNECT spring boot to elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to connect spring boot (2.7.4) to elasticSearch 8.9.2 with a username and password.

I configured elastic with minimal authentication, in other words username, password

I tested the connection to elasticSearch which works well with the following CURL request: curl -X GET -u elastic:XXXXXXXXXXX  http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health -k

the get request in curl generated by postman works on the command line but does not work on postman

[image]

but when I try to connect with spring boot I get an http 401 error

```
2023-09-26 00:53:09.304 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [GET http://localhost:9200/] returned [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
2023-09-26 00:53:09.307 TRACE 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] tracer                                   : curl -iX GET 'http://localhost:9200/'
# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
# WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"
# WWW-Authenticate: ApiKey
# content-type: application/json
# content-length: 403
#
# {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}
2023-09-26 00:53:09.314 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] sistentCredentialsAuthenticationStrategy : Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, CredSSP, Digest, Basic]
2023-09-26 00:53:09.314 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] sistentCredentialsAuthenticationStrategy : Challenge for Negotiate authentication scheme not available
2023-09-26 00:53:09.314 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] sistentCredentialsAuthenticationStrategy : Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
2023-09-26 00:53:09.314 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] sistentCredentialsAuthenticationStrategy : Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available
2023-09-26 00:53:09.314 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] sistentCredentialsAuthenticationStrategy : Challenge for CredSSP authentication scheme not available
2023-09-26 00:53:09.314 DEBUG 35874 --- [/O dispatcher 1] sistentCredentialsAuthenticationStrategy : Challenge for Digest authentication scheme not available
2023-09-26 00:53:09.315 DEBUG 35874 --- [  restartedMain] org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient      : request [HEAD http://localhost:9200/product] returned [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
2023-09-26 00:53:09.315 TRACE 35874 --- [  restartedMain] tracer                                   : curl -iX HEAD 'http://localhost:9200/product'
# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
# WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"
# WWW-Authenticate: ApiKey
# content-type: application/json
# content-length: 417
#
2023-09-26 00:53:09.382  WARN 35874 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService' defined in file [/Users/j/target/classes/com/sfkj/bestdeals/service/ProductService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.sfkj.bestdeals.repository.es.ProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on BestDealsServerApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=401} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]]; nested: ResponseException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]];
2023-09-26 00:53:09.387  INFO 35874 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-09-26 00:53:09.391  INFO 35874 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : Hikari - Shutdown initiated...
2023-09-26 00:53:09.399  INFO 35874 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : Hikari - Shutdown completed.
2023-09-26 00:53:09.403  INFO 35874 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-09-26 00:53:09.425  INFO 35874 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-26 00:53:09.454 ERROR 35874 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService' defined in file [/Users//service/ProductService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.sfkj.bestdeals.repository.es.ProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on BestDealsServerApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=401} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]]; nested: ResponseException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
    at com.sfkj.BestDealsServerApplication.main(BestDealsServerApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.sfkj.bestdeals.repository.es.ProductRepository defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on BestDealsServerApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=401} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]]; nested: ResponseException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]];
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is RestStatusException{status=401} org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]]; nested: ResponseException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]];
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$instantiateClass$5(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:579) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.instantiateClass(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:579) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:544) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:74) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:325) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.RestStatusException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]]; nested: ResponseException[method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]];
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:601) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:584) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.doExists(RestIndexTemplate.java:106) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractIndexTemplate.exists(AbstractIndexTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:87) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:2458) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2184) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2154) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:1279) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(RestIndexTemplate.java:106) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:582) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.4.3.jar:4.4.3]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [HEAD], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/product], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:347) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:313) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:288) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2699) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171) ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.17.6.jar:7.17.6]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

in my config , I tested each of these bean individually :

```
    @Bean
    public RestClient client1() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "6e8SxNuzU6q8R5"));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                        return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                });

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient client() {
        String serverUrl = "https://localhost:9200";

        // Create the low-level client
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create("https://localhost:9200"))
                .setDefaultHeaders(new Header[] { new BasicHeader("Authorization",
                        "ApiKey " + "aFhqeHlZb0JpZ29fRnJtNUEzb2E6dW10dlZnRHlSUzY1VUhpdVhzWXQwdw==") })
                .build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // And create the API client
        ElasticsearchClient esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
        return esClient;
    }
    public  ElasticsearchClient getElasticsearchClient() {
        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200));

        HttpClientConfigCallback httpClientConfigCallback = (httpClientBuilder) -> {
            final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("elastic", "6e8SxNuzU6q8R5"));

            return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        };
        builder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientConfigCallback);

        RestClient restClient = builder.build();
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    }
```

I have the same error http 401 error.

in the pom i have :

```
            <dependency>
      <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.17.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: `String serverUrl = "https://localhost:9200"` I see that your server is http, not https?

Comment: with the CURL request, I manage to connect with http so I suppose it is http and moreover I have a minimal security configuration on elastic so no ssl

Answer (score 0):

you need to add elasticsearch properties in your application.properties:

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=https://localhost:9200
spring.elasticsearch.rest.username=username
spring.elasticsearch.rest.password=password
```